# How to override default CSS in cakePHP 1.3?

Tags: css, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I'm running into a bit of a problem with my search plugin CSS. It doesn't apply some of the CSS rules I placed on /plugin/searchable/webroot/css/searchable_style. I think it is being overridden by the cakephp default CSS which I used with my application. Should I edit the generic css for my application or there's a way to bypass the generic CSS then apply what's on /plugin/searchable/webroot/css/searchable_style? I also tried
    css('/searchable/css/searchable_style'); ?>
and put it on every view and it worked but not all.

Thank you,
Lyman

Comment: I assume the plugin's css gets loaded. If so, do some of the css rules in the plugin get overriden by css rules in the main css? Can you give an example?

Comment: Correct, the plugin's css gets loaded because when I change a css attribute from the plugin's css, the change takes effect except for the button. Here's my code: echo $this->Form->submit('Search', array('div' => array('id' => 'search-submit'). Instead of applying 'search-submit' div id, it loads up the main css'.

Comment: what do you mean "loads up the main css"? Aren't they both loaded? (main css & plugin css). Try to debug this a little: does the div have the id? is there a typo? (_ instead of - maybe).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place your css file *searchable_style* to webroot/css folder: then use it in **app/views/layouts/default.ctp** (if you have) OR include this line to your home or landing layout

```
echo $this->Html->css('/searchable/css/searchable_style');
```

This will definitely work. but if you rename the `plugins` folder to `plugin` as your question, then it will cause problem. Please check all folder naming and retry.

Comment: This should also work: `$this->Html->css('cake.generic' , '/searchable/css/searchable_style');`, no need to copy it.

Comment: I think OP wants a plugin solution, so in theory he should be able to keep said CSS in his plugin folder out of the web root.

Comment: I don't have default.ctp on /plugin/searchable/views not even a layout folder. Should I create /plugin/searchable/views/layout/default.ctp then do echo $this->Html->css('/searchable/css/searchable_style');?

Comment: @Lyman I'm not talking about plugin default.ctp. what is your site's landing or home page

Comment: ecosystem/tickets then on index.ctp i have this line <?php echo $this->element('form', array('plugin' => 'searchable')); which references to the form I have on the /searchable/views/elements/form.ctp with the following codes: 
<?php
echo $form->create('SearchIndex', array(
  'url' => array(
    'plugin' => 'searchable',
    'controller' => 'search_indexes',
    'action' => 'index',
 'div' => array('class' => 'test')
  )
));
echo $this->Form->submit(
    'Send', 
    array('id' => 'search-button', 'class' => false)
);

Comment: here's the html page source:
<form action="/ecosystem/searchable/search_indexes/index/div:Array" id="SearchIndexIndexForm" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8"><div style="display:none;">
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="POST" /></div>
<div class="input text"><label for="search-text">Search</label><input name="data[SearchIndex][term]" type="text" id="search-text" />
</div>

<div class="submit"><input id="search-button" type="submit" value="Send" />
</div>

see the class="submit"? don't know where it's coming from.

Comment: @theCodeParadox, I got it! This code fixed it:

$options = array(
 'label' => 'Go',
 'id' => 'search-submit',
 'div' => array(
 'class' => false
 )
);
echo $this->Form->end($options);

Sorry for the 'what the heck is this' code. You're prob'ly still trying to figure it. Thank you all for the answers.